# Redux axios request cancellation

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a React Native application with Redux actions and reducers. I'm using the redux-thunk dispatch for waiting the asyncron calls. There is an action in my application:

```
export const getObjects = (id, page) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(`URL`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({ type: OBJECTS, payload: response });
            }).catch(error => {
                throw new Error(`Error: objects -> ${error}`);
            });
    };
};
```

That's working properly, but sometimes the user click on the back button before the action finished the request, and I must cancel it. How can I do it in a separated action? I [read this](https://gist.github.com/mzabriskie/ec3a25dd45dfa0de92c2), but I didn't find any option in axios for abort. I read about the axios [cancellation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#cancellation), but it's create a cancel method on the function scope and I can't return, because the the JS don't support multiple returns.

What is the best way to cancel axios request in an other Redux action?

Comment: An alternative way to do what you want is to let axios complete the request, but set a flag `canceled: true` in state dispatching another action (e.g. setCanceled). When the request finishes and the promise resolves, you first check the canceled flag. If it is true, you won't dispatch the success action. Does it solve your case?

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend using something like RxJS + Redux Observables which provides you with cancellable observables.

This solution requires a little bit of learning, but I believe it's a much more elegant way to handle asynchronous action dispatching versus `redux-thunk` which is only a partial solution to the problem.

I suggest watching Jay Phelps introduction [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AslncyG8whg) which may help you understand better the solution I'm about to propose.

A `redux-observable` epic enables you to dispatch actions to your store while using RxJS Observable functionalities. As you can see below the `.takeUntil()` operator lets you piggyback onto the `ajax` observable and stop it if elsewhere in your application the action `MY_STOPPING_ACTION` is dispatched which could be for instance a route change action that was dispatched by `react-router-redux` for example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const GET_OBJECTS = 'GET_OBJECTS';
const GET_OBJECTS_SUCCESS = 'GET_OBJECTS_SUCCESS';
const GET_OBJECTS_ERROR = 'GET_OBJECTS_ERROR';
const MY_STOPPING_ACTION = 'MY_STOPPING_ACTION';

function getObjects(id) {
  return {
    type: GET_OBJECTS,
    id,
  };
}

function getObjectsSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: GET_OBJECTS_SUCCESS,
    data,
  };
}

function getObjectsError(error) {
  return {
    type: GET_OBJECTS_ERROR,
    data,
  };
}

const getObjectsEpic = (action$, store) = action$
  .ofType(GET_OBJECTS)
  .switchMap(action => Observable.ajax({
      url: `http://example.com?id=${action.id}`,
    })
    .map(response => getObjectsSuccess(response))
    .catch(error => getObjectsError(error))         
    .takeUntil(MY_STOPPING_ACTION)
  );
```